# Keep CSS Formatting in folder assets Yii

Tags: css, yii

I used [yiibooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/) I have changed many styles under /assets/73dd67/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-min.css

But when I changed my webapp name, the CSS files not found, I mean the folder '73dd67' changed to '253ft6'.
The same case when I moved my webapp to another computer. The '73dd67' folder changed again in another name.

What can I do so I can keep the CSS formatting?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset folder have only cached files. You made changes in cached file not actual file. 
So find the actual location of bootstrap-min.css and do your changes. After doing changes, just remove all cache folders inside the asset folder. Then you can see the output in next refresh itself.

Hope you are using yIIbooster as extension.  So do your changes in extension `css/bootstrap-min.css` file.

Comment: I use yiibooster as extensions. but when I view page source (I use GChrome), the CSS files refer to assets folder. The actual location is in /protected/extensions/bootstrap/assets. So how to make my webapp access the actual CSS files? I have checked my CSS files, there's no bootstrap-min.css

Comment: Yii create assets file from the their actual location. You may have css file in assets/css folder or css/ folder

Comment: Okay I got it thank you. I copied the files in the bootstrap/assets to /css and that's okay